# Error:Server chose TLSv1 using Java 8 and Glassfish 3.1.2.2

Tags: sql-server, spring, ssl-certificate, glassfish-3, tls1.0

I changed the server to java 8 to avoid having problems with TLS, but now it is giving me the following error:

> Caused by: com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException:Error: "Server chose TLSv1, but that protocol version is not enabled or not supported by the client.".
> Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: Server chose TLSv1, but that protocol version is not enabled or not supported by the client.

**Things I've tried:**

1. In the file osgi.properties I added jre-1.8=${jre-1.6},com.sun.tracing.
2. -Dhttps.protocols=TLSv1.2 to the server JVM Options.
3. In the file  domain.xml tls11-enabled="false" tls12-enabled="true" tls-enabled="false".
4. I have tried in the url connection ";encrypt=true;trustServerCertificate=true" .

**But the error still appear.**

Could someone help me with other ideas that can solve the error, please

Comment: What does `PRINT @@VERSION` return on your SQL Server?

Comment: Yes, it is a SQL Server 2008 R2, from an old system that now needs to connect to a cloud system

Comment: 2008 R2 supports TLS1.2 if you kept it up to date when it *was* supported. Sounds like not only are you using a version of SQL Server that had been out of support for **4 years** but you haven't installed an update on the server since *2015* (you didn't tell us what `@@VERSION` return, so I assume you installed some updates prior)... The real problem isn't your application, it's your lack of keeping your software up to date and secure.

Comment: I understand and agree with you however this is a recent job that I was assigned and I am doing my best to make it work.

Comment: i think you got it the other way around, `"Server chose TLSv1, but that protocol version is not enabled or not supported by the client.".` to me means that sql server wants to use TLSv1, but you're trying to force TLS1.2 on java side. You need to do it the other way around, ie. downgrade the java TLS.

Comment: Then why not at least update the SQL Server to the most recent SP and CU? It would have TLS1.2 support then. Then scream at your manager every 10 minutes until they upgrade that instance to a supported version. Ideally, every 5 minutes (this looks like a joke, but I am *not* joking).

Comment: Just to ask again, what *does* `PRINT @@VERSION;` return?

Comment: Thanks siggemannen, the problem is that I cannot downgrade the java because it must be connected through a webservices to another system that requires tls 1.2, so if I do I will return to the previous error

Comment: I'm going to try Thom, thank you.

Comment: you might get lucky with encrypt=false, but yeah, better try to upgrade me thinks

Comment: Seems like you're giving more reason why using the version of SQL Server you are needs to stop and that it's not a case of wanting to get the server supported, but you **must**.

Comment: As well as the latest updates for SQL Server https://support.microsoft.com/en-gb/topic/kb2527041-archived-how-to-obtain-the-latest-service-pack-for-sql-server-2008-r2-1bf2c2f9-8a3d-54c4-2953-f35a14d17d6e you also need to install the latest Windows updates, and if you are on (I guess) an old version of Windows you need to enable TLS1.2 (you can use the free IIS Crypto tool for this). Ideally upgrade SQL Server and Windows to a supported version.